# Xcode iOS как оставить отзыв о программе непосредственно из программы?

Tags: xcode, ios

Добрый день!

Есть идея реализовать оставление отзывов и оценок о программе непосредственно из самой программы, без необходимости захода на сайт itunes. Можно ли такое сделать?

Comment: Нельзя

Answer (score 1):

Нет, такое сделать нельзя. Можно из программы открыть напрямую страницу своего приложения в iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Помню что когда-то давно использовал для чего-то подобного [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate), но подробностей уже не помню - показывает ли он в приложении рейтинг в программе или перенаправляет в апстор, по-моему, второе